# AAAAMMDDHH24MISS in Java

Tags: java, string, calendar

How do make this return `AAAAMMDDHH24MISS` in Java.

Example: `20071225123000`

My code

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("AAAAMMDDHH24MISS");

    Date d = format.parse("10/10/2007 08:10:23");  

    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");  
    String formatada = format2.format(d);  

    System.out.println(formatada);  

} catch (ParseException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: You `SimpleDateFormat` format string makes no sense.  There are no "A"'s in the SDF JavaDoc, and I don't know what MISS is.  Plus, the date string you are passing into your SDF is not even remotely in the format you express, its in `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" format.  I am very confussed as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the source format before parsing the source. Then converting it to the desired format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy H:m:s");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddHms");

Date d = sourceFormat.parse("10/10/2007 08:10:23");

String formatada = format.format(d);

System.out.println(formatada);
```